# facebook user info storing in database

Tags: php, mysql, facebook

My website provide the user to create an account and log in with facebook. The user table contain: userId (`generated by $userId = uniqid(rand(), true;`, if user creating his own account). password, salt, email, date joined.

1st question:

I am not sure if what I am doing with facebook is safe. Right now I am getting user ID from facebook and sending it to server with xmlhttpRequest object. Then server store it under userID and leave other columns blank.

2nd question:

Is the possibilities significant for the facebook userID to overlap with normal account's userid generated by `uniquid(rand(), true)`

3rd question:

is it safe to use client side login? I mean even my App ID will be seen by users.

4th question:
In order to tell if the entry is a facebook account or normal account, should I add another column in database, true=facebook account, false=normal account. Or should I just check to see if password column is blank for the certain account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [thepointless.com](http://www.thepointless.com) as an example, every user gets an auto-incremented ID, including facebook users. External authentication services are recognized by the `username`, which contains a URL for "irregular" users:

```
+----------+------------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| Field    | Type             | Null | Key | Default           | Extra          |
+----------+------------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| user_id  | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment |
| username | varchar(255)     | YES  | UNI | NULL              |                |
| password | varchar(255)     | YES  |     | NULL              |                |
| created  | timestamp        | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |                |
| userdata | mediumtext       | YES  |     | NULL              |                |
| admin    | tinyint(1)       | YES  |     | 0                 |                |
| name     | varchar(765)     | YES  |     | NULL              |                |
+----------+------------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
```

Facebook users' usernames are the URLs of their graph data, like `http://graph.facebook.com/8643372`. It isn't necessary in your system to point to something real, so long as it identifies the domain and an external [unique] ID. It just so happens in this case that the user's public graph object is a short, predictable URL.

Normal users are restricted from prefixing their usernames with `http` or `https`. The `password` is left blank. And the `userdata` stores the JSON or XML provided by the 3rd party authentication service.

A fully client-side login shouldn't generally be trusted by *server-side* logic. But, server-side validation of a JavaScript initiated login is generally not difficult. And there's no reason not to trust, at least on a preliminary basis, an entirely client-side authentication **on the client**.

And as far as I know, there's no need to keep your App ID a secret. It's your "App **Secret**" that needs to remain hidden.